# I retrieve the data from firestore but , how to create Borders around the output data in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  body:
```

...
SelectableText("Address1: "+e.data["address"]["addressline1"]),

```
                              SelectableText("Address2: "+e.data["address"]["addressline2"]),

                              SelectableText("Pincode: "+e.data["address"]["pincode"]),
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Container widget

```
Container( decoration:Boxdecoration(border:null,borderRadius:null))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the SelectableText with an Container and setting it's [decoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html):

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
  ),
  child: SelectableText(
    'Hello! How are you?',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  )
)
```